# Taylor Series and finding a function

Tags: taylor-expansion

I've got the following question:

Give a function whose 2nd order Taylor series at $x=1$ is $10-7(x-1)+4(x-1)^2+o((x-1)^3)$

---

All I can work out so far is that $f(1) = 10$ (using the standard taylor series formula), that's the only tangible piece of info I have so far. Would really appreciate if someone could walk me through the rest of this?

Comment: is that last coefficient a 0?

Comment: You also know $\frac{df}{dx}(1)=7, \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(1)=4$

Comment: One possible answer is $10-7(x-1)+4(x-1)^2$.